# Calamaris for Squid Proxy Report "Incoming TCP-requests by host" sort by Byte

Tags: tcp, proxy, report, squid

I have to use Calamaris V3.x for Squid Proxy in my Network and just want to sort the "Incoming TCP-requests by host" Report by Byte.

Here is my Version of Calamaris and my conf.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Av8IKRixEXbXa2iTkNKAAUvHyno

Thats just a Little piece of work for you Perl5 experts.

Comment: Using links to your code is not accepted practice at SO, you should show your code, correctly formatted in order to get help. Note that links break and makes questions such as these useful in the future. Please read the how to ask a question in the SO help docs

Comment: It´s to much to post it in one Question and to make sure that everyone get´s the right script i uploaded it here

Comment: I would suggest you take the time to read through all the documents on SO regarding asking questions starting here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Then move on to read the docs in their entirety. Welcome to SO